# IE css problems when styling form

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

This [site](http://dev.hairatporters.co.uk/contact) works perfectly in Firefox, although in IE7 the contact form is not displaying correctly.

1. Input/Textarea is not reading the background image and color properties (style.css line:273)

   ```
   #contact_form input, #contact_form textarea, #contact_form select {
     background: url("../images/input-bg.gif") repeat-x scroll left center #2E190B;
     border: 1px solid #FF8A00;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
     padding-top: 6px;
   }
   ```
2. Radio options for the "Send me a copy", in IE has a white background color (style.css line:280)

   ```
   #contact_form fieldset .checkbox input, #contact_form fieldset .radio input {
     background: none;
     border: none;
     display: block;
     float: left;
     padding: 0;
   }
   ```
3. Submit buttons, in IE these are white and no background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problems are caused by the `filter` property being defined for form elements, specifically in the `.form input` and `.form textarea` rules. Try removing those filter definitions.

Answer (score 1):

All of these attributes has been overridden, but in IE, `filter` attribute is still in active

```
background: #F6F8F9;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F6F8F9 0%, #E5EBEE 50%, #D7DEE3 51%, #F5F7F9 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#F6F8F9), color-stop(50%,#E5EBEE), color-stop(51%,#D7DEE3), color-stop(100%,#F5F7F9));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F6F8F9 0%,#E5EBEE 50%,#D7DEE3 51%,#F5F7F9 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F6F8F9 0%,#E5EBEE 50%,#D7DEE3 51%,#F5F7F9 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F6F8F9 0%,#E5EBEE 50%,#D7DEE3 51%,#F5F7F9 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f8f9', endColorstr='#f5f7f9',GradientType=0 );
background: linear-gradient(top, #F6F8F9 0%,#E5EBEE 50%,#D7DEE3 51%,#F5F7F9 100%);
```

`background` attribute and `filter` attribute can be together in IE, so set:

```
#contact_form .btn {
...
filter: none;
}

#contact_form input, #contact_form textarea, #contact_form select {
...
filter: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I see that your site uses jQuery.

Why don't you use one of the nice plugins to manage forms ?

[Here](http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements), some of them are listed and linked.

Comment: How does this fix the problems in IE7?